# Is it possible to schedule a step in Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops

What ideally I need to do is run a Jenkins pipeline that will run immediately after I start the execution , checking out code, running a build but just running the deployment in a particular date/time. So Would it be possible to schedule a particular step in jenkins pipeline? This step would be executed at date/time provided by user input. If that’s not possible is there any alternative way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

The is no such way to schedule the steps of the Jenkins Job. But the Following approach may help you to achieve what you are trying to do.

Step-1: Install "Schedule Build Plugin" which will provide you a capability to schedule the job to run on certain data and time.

Step-2: Create a pipeline job with the code that you want to execute at a certain date and time. (Note: You will not schedule this job at this time)

Step-3: Remove the pipeline code that you already copied to another pipeline job and add a build step to schedule the build on the second pipeline that you will create in step-2.